# Adding SKNode to SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game and I'm trying to add a SKNode to the GameScene, the problem is that when I run it, it crashes and displays that the problem is when I am adding the SKNode to the GameScene. Here my code.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
 {
      var worldsNode:SKNode = SKNode.alloc()
      self.addChild(worldsNode)  //Xcode says that here is the problem.
 }
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: there is no alloc init pattern in swift. You just use `SKNode()` which calls the init method and returns a fully allocated and initialised object. For more info look at the swift docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of `SKNode` in swift try the following code

```
var worldsNode = SKNode()
self.addChild(worldsNode)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I just forgot that swift has no alloc, got confused, you know, working Obj-C and Swift at the same time. Thanks!